# Extracting and formatting the required numbers from a bytearray in python

Tags: python-bytearray

question in python.

I was trying to get data from a BLE device,

The following bytearray was output.

```
b'\x32\x33\x30\x38\x31\x37\x32\x32\x34\x35'#2308172245

b'\x44\x31\x32\x35\x43\x30\x39\x34\x35' # D125C0945
```

I want to extract and format it as follows.

```
23/08/17/22:45

data : 12.5 command 0945
```

Two bytearrays are output and I want to format each of them.

Can you please tell me how to do this in a smart way?

Any help will be really appreciated.

I have tried to do the following, but I feel there is a bit of wasted movement and would like to know a better way.
(Also not a decimal point.)

```
 import datetime

 # getdata = above data

 data = (list(map(str,getdata.decode('utf-8'))))

 if(data[0] == 'C' and len(data) == 9):
        print(f"data : {(''.join(data[1:3]))} command {data[5:8]}")

 elif(len(data) == 10):
        m_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(''.join(data),'%y%m%d%H%M')
        print(f"date&time : {m_time}")
```